# Generating probability function.

Tags: probability

Let $X_1$ be a random Poisson variable with mean $u_1$, and let $X_2$ be a random Poisson variable with mean $u_2$ independent of $X_1$

a) What is the probability that $X_1 + X_2 = n$?

b)  What are t.he mean, variance, and other cumulants of $2X_1 + 3X_2$?

$$P(X_1 =k) = \frac{e^{-u_1}u_1^k}{k!}$$
$$P(X_2 =k) = \frac{e^{-u_2}u_2^k}{k!}$$

$$G_{x_1 + X_2} (z)  = G_{X_1}(z)G_{X_2}(z) = e^{(u_1 + u_2 )(z-1)} $$
$G$ is a generating function of probability.
And solution for a) is:
$$\frac{e^{-u_1 - u_2 }(u_1 + u_2)^n}{n!}$$
I don't understand why. Please explain me.

And please me hint with b).
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

(a)

The sum of two independent Poisson random variables is Poisson, with the sum of the rates. In symbols, if $X_ \sim Pois(\lambda_1)$ and independently $X_2 \sim Pois(\lambda_2)$ then $$Y = X_1 + X_2 \sim Pois(\lambda_1 + \lambda_2).$$
Essentially, your last generating function proves this. (The product of generating functions gives the generating function of the sum of independent random variables.) Now let $\lambda = \lambda_1 + \lambda_2.$ Then $P\{Y = n\} = \exp(-\lambda) \lambda^n / n!,$ for $n = 0, 1, \dots .$

Examples:  **(1)** Suppose I have two clay-like lumps of uranium ore. The number of particles emitted by each is very well modeled by a Poisson distribution, say
the clicks per minute in my Geiger counter is $X_1 \sim Pois(12)$ for the first lump and $X_2 \sim Pois(10)$ for the second. If I mold the two lumps together into a larger lump, it seems natural that that the total number of clicks per minute from the larger lump is $X_1 + X_2 \sim Pois(22).$

**(2)** A similar argument could be made for the number of claims of a particular type per  month when two insurance companies merge.

**(3)** Consider the number of Poisson events in each minute along a time line is modeled as $Pois(\lambda).$ Consider two time intervals $(0, 1]$ and $(1, 2]$.
Then the number of events in the first interval is $X_1 \sim Pois(\lambda)$ and the number in the number in the second interval is $X_2 \sim Pois(\lambda)$. These two random variables are independent because the intervals are disjoint.
The number of events in $(0, 2]$ is $Y = X_1 + X_2 \sim Pois(2\lambda)$.

The probability of no events in $(0, 1]$ is $\exp(-\lambda)$, the probability of no events in the second interval $(1, 2]$ is also $\exp(-\lambda)$. By independence, the product of these probabilities is $[\exp(-\lambda)]^2 = \exp(-2\lambda),$ which is the probability of no events in $(0,2].$

**In conclusion,** if the sum of two independent Poisson random variables were not
Poisson with added rates, none of the intuitive modeling scenarios would make sense.

(b)

$E(2X_! + 3X_2) = 2E(X_1) + 3E(X_2) = 2\lambda_1 + 3\lambda_2,$ by a formula for expectations that should be in a probability book readily at  hand, and by the fact the the mean of $X \sim POIS(\lambda) = \lambda.$ (Independence not required.)

A similar formula for variances of *independent* random variables $X$ and $Y$ is
$$V(aX + bY) = a^2V(X) + b^2V(Y),$$ from which you can answer the second part.
What is the variance of a Poisson random variable?

Comment: $2X_1 + 3X_2$ is *not* Poisson, but you can get its MGF.